# Hover effect works only in inspect elements

Tags: css, frontend

So I had no problem with this code, but suddenly hover effect didn't respond when I put my mouse on it, it only responds when I click "Hover" in inspect elements. Would be great if I get some help.

```css
.box {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 34rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px black;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  width: 34rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 27%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover::before {
  opacity: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <h1 class="service-title" style="color: black;">Services</h1>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box box1">
      <span class="box-text">Weight Lifting</span>
      <span class="box-desc">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maiores cumque quod atque, iusto maxime natus. Obcaecati nisi adipisci doloribus!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the box into the background with negative `z-index` therefore the mouse hover is never registered (but it can still be trigged with chrome dev tools).

```css
.box {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 34rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px black;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  width: 34rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 27%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover::before {
  opacity: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <h1 class="service-title" style="color: black;">Services</h1>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box box1">
      <span class="box-text">Weight Lifting</span>
      <span class="box-desc">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maiores cumque quod atque, iusto maxime natus. Obcaecati nisi adipisci doloribus!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```